# Terraform to grant multiple GCP roles in cross account access

Tags: terraform

I have terraform locals as:

```
locals {
  cross_account_roles = jsondecode([
  {
    "sa_name" : "admin-sa",
    "from_project_id": "projectA",
    "to_project_id": "projectB",
    "roles": ["roles/storageAdmin", "roles/computeAdmin"]
  },
   {
    "sa_name" : "workshop-sa",
    "from_project_id": "projectC",
    "to_project_id": "projectB",
    "roles": ["roles/storageAdmin"]
  }
])
}
```

using this json list, I am creating a `google_project_iam_member` resource as:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "cross_account_roles" {
  for_each = { for idx, val in local.cross_account_roles : idx => val }
  project  = each.value.to_project_id
  role     = each.value.roles
  member   = "serviceAccount:${each.value.sa_name}@${each.value.from_project_id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

But since the role needs to be a string and it only take 1 value at a time and my locals role is a list. I think I have to use `flatten` but could not work it out.

Comment: I believe the roles you intend in your inputs are different than the role intended by the resource parameter argument.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard I did not understand.